# How can I multiply together every nth cell in a row to get the product?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to calculate the product of the investment returns (compound interest), which in this instance would give a return of 162%:

[image]

Additional stock return data will be added in future, so I need a formula that compounds every nth (2nd) value. I am able to sum the cells using: 
`=SUMIF(ARRAYFORMULA(MOD((COLUMN(A2:H2)-COLUMN(A2)+1),2)),0,A2:H2)`

However I cannot find an equivalent 'PRODUCTIF' function and have not been able to make a formula that works. Writing the formula out long hand would be:
`=B2*D2*F2*H2`

Comment: I have a good way to do this, but it'd be a lot easier to demonstrate on a shared sheet than in the abstract.  Can you share a quick (editable) sample?

Comment: Thank you for your response. The answer that I've ticked has answered this for me, but thank you regardless!

Comment: understood,  I'll post up what my method is and maybe it will work for you too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Product formula should be like Sum formula but putting 1 for odd columns:

```
=ArrayFormula(PRODUCT(IF(MOD(COLUMN(A2:H2)-COLUMN(A2)+1,2),1,A2:H2)))
```

[image]

Comment: You are the man! Thank you, I even tried something like by nesting the Product and If, but you've got it! My actual problem is a bit more complicated than this, but I think that I can use this solution to make that.

Answer (score 2):

I guess i'm a little confused.  doesn't PRODUCT() just ignore text?

Doesn't `=PRODUCT(2:2)` work?

Comment: You're right - it does! It ignores blanks as well so there is nothing wrong with doing it this way  (unless one of the stock names was a number which looks very unlikely).

Comment: I actually posted a simplified version of the problem as I thought it would be too convoluted if I posted the whole issue. What you have posted would not work for my exact issue, but that is useful to know that Product skips text, for future reference.

Comment: hi @programmer1  I think i can help if you post a more accurate sample. some people don't like sharing an editable sheet for some reason so here's an empty one.  Paste in something resembling what you have and i'll show you how to do conditional products across the columns and even all the way down all the rows with just a single formula.  I can have it skip any pattern of columns.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12LUI9FODpaq38KmefBXY1UwbGkbN8YeHbv1sM95oMuI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi @MattKing ! I'll never turn down an offer of help! I have input my table into your spreadsheet. I need to calculate the compound percentage return, when given the buy and sell price of each individual stock.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following formula:

```
=PRODUCT(TRANSPOSE(2:2))
```

and format the result as `Percent` from the menu

[image]

Functions used:

- [`TRANSPOSE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262)
- [`PRODUCT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093502)

**EDIT**
As **[correctly noted by Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62124869/1527780)**, an even simpler formula can also give the correct results.

```
=PRODUCT(2:2)
```